# Does all Eigenvectors of $A$ lie on the vector space of $Ax$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> The problem is with the last  part of the following question:

[image]

---

I will write my results to the first parts which are correct here :

Three Eigenvalues:

$$\lambda_1=1 , \lambda_2=2 , \lambda_3=3$$

Corresponding Eigenvectors:

> $$e_1 = –2j + k$$
>
> $$e_2 = i + j $$
>
> $$e_3 = 2i + 2j + k$$

---

*I proved the  second part sucessfully:*

> $r$ is the parametric equation

$$r=te+sf$$

$$A(te+sf) = tAe+sAf= (t\lambda) e + (s \mu) f$$

Therefore we can conclude the statement

---

*Now the problem is:*

How to do the last part, what three planes?

I don't understand what's happening.

> My book has taken two pairs of my three Eigenvectors and done the cross product to find the normal vector, since there are 3 combinations so they have got 3 equations, like this:
>
> $e_1 × e_2 = –i + j + 2k ⇒ x – y – 2z = 0$
>
> $e_1 × e_3 = 2i – j – 2k ⇒ 2x – y – 2z = 0$
>
> $e_2 × e_3 = i – j ⇒ x – y = 0$

But I don't understand how this works, because I found the three Eigenvectors of A, so **ALLL three Eigenvectors lie on the same plane**, so then cross product of any vectors in one plane gives its normal vector which is the same for all. So there won't be any equations, Please help.

---

The book **contradicts** my belief that :

**All Eigenvectors of $A$ lie on the plane which represents the vector space $Ax$**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : All 3 eigenvectors do not lie on the same plane. If they do, the matrix is nilpotent and this matrix is not, since the eigenvalues are distinct. The eigenvectors span a space but that does not mean that they are on a plane. The space, in this case, is 3-dimensional whereas the plane is 2-dimensional. You can see that the eigenvectors are linearly independent which means that they do not lie on the same plane but span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

You can visualize in 3 dimensions that a pair of eigenvectors will span a plane. Therefore you have $3 \choose 2 $ $=3$ planes.

Comment: Linearly independant means that it's a basis, so doesnt the vectors need to be on the plane to span it?

Comment: Yep. The 3 eigenvectors do form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. You are right about the fact that they are on a plane. But they are on a 3-dimensional hyperplane. Your question refers to 2-dimensional planes and not 3-d hyperplanes. I hope that clears your doubt

Comment: How is it 2 dimensional? wait let me Think

Comment: If you add a vector out of the plane with the plane , you end up outside the plane (outside the vector space). So how is it correct to say that the Eigenvectors are linearly independant are not in the vector space (plane) ? Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Let's take any of the two eigenvectors of matrix $A$. If you linearly combine these two vectors, you will get a plane. If you add any two vectors in that plane, the resultant vector will also lie in the plane. I hope you can visualize that. Therefore, the plane is a 2-dimensional subspace of $R^3$. 

Now, if instead of 2 eigenvectors, you start with 3 eigenvectors and linearly combine them, you get a 3-dimensional vector space ( can also be read as 3-D plane ). 

If the 3 eigenvectors were linearly dependent, you would get a 1 or 2 dimensional vector space and not a 3-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Oh I think I got it :D thank you very much